# How to check system power logs and confirming system is going into modern standby/S0?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I need to confirm whether the system is going into modern standby /S0 state with the help of event logs, I have tried journalctl command for checking the logs but for standby and Moderstandy it was showing the same command.

Need to know how to check it, Please help me on this

Thanks